# .htaccess mod_rewrite - how to exclude addon domain from rewrite rule?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, cpanel

my main hosting domain require ssl, so the htaccess transform every url request to https.

but i have on the same hosting another domain, with cpanel dir structure ("public_htmml/addon-domain.com")

The public_html htaccess is the only I can configure.  I need to exclude from the rewrite the directory of the add-on domain.  so when a user type www.addondoamin.com or without the www, the htaccess will not do anything. o/w, i get many errors and the addon domain mirror to the main domain.

notice that

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public_html/addon-domain.com/.*$
```

didnt work.

So, here is the htaccess.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]


    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !promotion
     RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

10x very much!  hope anybody can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this which can be placed anywhere above your current rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?addon-domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^.*$ '-' [L]
```

Comment: Hey!  it works well on desktop!  finally.  BUTTT  on mobile, when u ask for the addon-domain without the www, it redirects to "https : // addon-domain . com" with a certificate error.   HOW CAN I MODIFY THE HTACCESS SO IT WILL WORK BOTH WITH WWW AND WITHOUT?  many thanks!

Comment: Your mobile browser may have cached the 301 redirect from before. Try clearing your mobile browser's cache. The above code does account for www and non-www through the use of an optional match in the regular expression.

Comment: @jedifans Please i know this is an old post but was just wondering how to edit this rule if you have multiple addon domains?

Comment: @AgbogidiMichael you should be able to repeat the above for as many domains as needed, or if you are skilled in regular expressions you can edit the current regex in the answer.

Comment: @jedifans Thanks. Not skilled in regex. So i can put them like this

Comment: @jedifans
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?addon-domain1\.com$
RewriteRule ^.*$ '-' [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?addon-domain2\.com$
RewriteRule ^.*$ '-' [L]`