# .htaccess Issue on "Deluxe" Hosting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I'm no .htaccess guru. I barely understand what's going on. I have a shared hosting account on GoDaddy that allows for unlimited domains to be hosted. (I know, GoDaddy isn't my best option)

The primary domain files are located in the root directory and add on domains are in sub directories.

My main site is using a custom MVC Framework. I have two directories in it, app, and public, and an .htaccess file telling it to go to the "public" directory. I think this file is causing my issue (500 errors on my other sites)

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
   RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

My question is, is there a change I can make so that it doesn't effect my other sites? Is it something I'd have to change each time I add an add-on domain? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out, and makes sense that you have to change up the .htaccess file a bit in this particular case. The .htaccess file when placed in the root directory affects all sub folders so if you have a hosting account set up like mine, you will need to do this.... I actually found the answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39062158/htaccess-mod-rewrite-how-to-exclude-addon-domain-from-rewrite-rule?rq=1) stack overflow question.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?addon-domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^.*$ '-' [L]
```